# What do parameters of Snap.svg's unclick do?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Snap.svg is a js library to process SVG in DOM. It has a method `unclick`and a number of similarly named methods. Their purpose is to unbind event handlers. According to docs they all have callback parameters. What purpose do these parameters serve? Is executing these methods without parameters not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Elements can have more than one click handler. You need to pass in the original click handler so it know which one to remove.